# PHP send mail error when receiving attachments - octet-stream; name=""

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I have a problem regarding PHP send mail. I am trying to send an attachment with the help of PHP from an online form. The data in the email I received is perfectly fine but the attachment sometimes comes like :

```
2 application octet-stream; name=""
```

(this would be a plain text as an attachment with this name). What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php 
// if button is pressed - ACTION
if (isset($_POST['reg_application'])) {

// get fields into variables
$firstname = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);;
$lastname = strip_tags($_POST['lastname']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);

// get other form fields into variables
$country = strip_tags($_POST['country']);
$experience = strip_tags($_POST['experience']);
$englishlevel = strip_tags($_POST['englishlevel']);
$availability = strip_tags($_POST['availability']);
$licence = strip_tags($_POST['drivingLicence']);
$nursing = strip_tags($_POST['nursing']);
$signed = "Signed";



    //Deal with the email
    $to = 'example@example.com';
    $subject = "+1 $country - $firstname $lastname";

    //Deal with sending
        //$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
        $message = "ALL DETAILS\n\nFirst Name: $firstname\nLast Name: $lastname\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nCountry: $country\nExperience: $experience\nEnglish: $englishlevel\nAvailability: $availability\nDriving Licence: $licence\nNursing Experience: $nursing\nAccepted T&C: $signed";
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

        $headers = "From: example@example.com\r\nReply-To: daniel@hidd.co.uk";
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

        $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        header("Location: success.php?application-sent");

}


 ?>
```

Comment: You tagged this with phpmailer, but you're not using it - perhaps you should. You're also handling file uploads unsafely.

Comment: I must confess, I am practically new to php. Could you please elaborate this a bit. What am I doing wrong, maybe an example of how to do it better!

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
$name           = "Name";
$email      = "Email Address";
$to             = "$name <$email>";
$from           = "XYZ";
$subject        = "TEST SUBJECT";
$mainMessage    = "Hi, here's the file.";
$fileatt        = "./test.pdf";
$fileatttype    = "application/pdf";
$fileattname    = "newname.pdf";
$headers        = "From: $from";
// File
$file           = fopen ( $fileatt, 'rb' );
$data           = fread ( $file, filesize ( $fileatt ) );
fclose ( $file );
// Attach the file
$semi_rand  = md5 ( time () );
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers       .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$message        = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "-{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $mainMessage . "\n\n";
$data           = chunk_split ( base64_encode ( $data ) );
$message      .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" . " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" . "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n" . "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";
// Send Email
if (mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers )) {   
    echo "The email was sent.";
} else {    
    echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
```